# After magento upgrade to 2.3.0 product image background suddenly not transparent

Tags: magento2.3.0

After upgrading magento from 2.2.3 to 2.3.0 only SOME of the product images suddenly have a background color similar to product color. All product images in attachment are the same file type.

Does anybody experience the same issue?

Thanks for suggestions!

[image: product images]

Answer (score 0):

Please run all these Command:

->cache:flush

->cache:clean

->setup:upgrade

->di:compile

->indexer:reindex

->static-content:deploy -f

Comment: thank you for the reply. Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue.